# Why does trying to change a TextView or show a toast within a timerTask freeze my app?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_track_income.*
import java.util.*
import kotlin.concurrent.timerTask

class TrackIncome : AppCompatActivity() {

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_track_income)

        val time: TextView = findViewById(R.id.time)
        val money: TextView = findViewById(R.id.money)
        val timer: Timer = Timer()  
        val calculateTime = timerTask {
            val milliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis()
            var seconds: Int = (milliseconds / 1000).toInt()
            val minutes = 1
            seconds %= 60
            print("seconds are " + seconds.toString()) 
            time.text = String.format("%d.%d", minutes,seconds)

        }
        Timer("timer", false).schedule(calculateTime,1000, 1000)

    }
    fun showToast(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Its toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

I noticed that if I write time.text within the `timerTask` object, or try to call `showToast()`, my app  will crash.

Furthermore when I try to comment out 
`"time.text = String.format("%d.%d", minutes,seconds)"` and run the app just using the print statement and examine `logcat`, the print statement doesn't show up either. I've already read other examples of people using the Timer object, so why doesn't my method work?

Comment: instead of print use Log.d() to view your result.

Answer (score 1):

`Toast` is a UI element so it needs to run on the `UI Thread`, not in a `background Thread`

**use [`runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)**

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
            Toast.makeText(yourContext, "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```